Falling into a loop when trying to reset MacBook Pro. What am I missing?
I have a Macbook Pro 2017 that I'm trying to reset, but I got into a loop:

I turned it on and get the black screen with the https://support.apple.com/mac/startup link.
Restarted and entered Recovery Mode. Went to Reinstall MacOS, but got stuck because the disk is full.
Went to Disk Utility and tried to erase the whole disk (APPLE SSD...), got the "Couldn't open device" error.
Tried to erase the Container disk2 inside the Apple SSD, got the "An internal state error occurred".
Tried to erase the Macintosh HD - Data inside of Container disk2 and got the same error as before after the step "Deleting Volume".
Tried to run First Aid in the same order as above, got "Problems were found with the partition map, which might prevent booting" on APPLE SSD, then "The verify or repair cannot be performed because one or more volumes are locked" on the Container disk2.

Tried to do all the above from the terminal as well, got the same errors.
This is the result of my diskutil list:
/dev/disk0 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  GUID_partition_scheme                           -
   1:  Apple_HFS                macOS Base System       2.1 GB

/dev/disk1 (internal):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  GUID_partition_scheme                           -
   1:  EFI                     EFI                     314.6 MB
   2:  Apple_APFS              Container disk2        121.0 GB

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  APFS Container Scheme   -                       121.0 GB
   1:  APFS Volume             Macintosh HD - Data     91.2 GB
   2:  APFS Volume             Preboot                 2.1 GB
   3:  APFS Volume             Recovery                1.2 GB
   4:  APFS Volume             VM                      3.2 GB
   5:  APFS Volume             Update                  9.3 GB

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       5.2 MB

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       524.3 KB

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       524.3 KB

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       524.3 KB

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       2.1 MB

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       524.3 KB

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:  TYPE                    NAME                    SIZE
   0:  untitled                -                       [SIZE]


I then tried to erase at least the VM, Update and Recovery partitions to free some space and try to reinstall MacOS again, but with no success. Is there anything else I can try? Thank you in advance!

I hate to say this but all the errors/problems you have run across point to a failed drive. "couldn't open device." And the fact that you can't operate on any partition/container on the drive. All that plus it's a Mac from 2017. So it's getting a little old but I do believe the SSD is replaceable. So a bit of bad news good news here.

Before you get support from a professional, many many people can get caught up trying to erase a part of the drive and not repartition it entirely. This is especially try if you boot to recovery on the drive itself and not using internet recovery.
Can you take cell phone pictures of the screen when you use disk utility to ensure you selected the correct item?

https://support.apple.com/en-us/102639

You’ll want to follow every single step and post if you can’t get to the 4 numbered items in the middle of the above page. Especially the https://support.apple.com/en-us/102639#nodisk
This might be the part where you call support and realize the drive needs repair. At that point you could try attaching an external drive and installing macOS on the external rather than fixing the internal. Then you will have a redundant system to run further disk repairs and checks to ensure you need that repair.
Once you’re sure you can internet recovery boot or have a second OS, you can use diskutil eraseDisk on the /dev/disk1 (internal): Instead of just trying to erase disk2s1 which is what it appears you are failing to accomplish.
